# Facebook messenger app security error with certbot certificate

Tags: facebook, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, facebook-messenger, certbot

I have a business website running using a free certificate using [letsencrypt.org](https://letsencrypt.org) and more specifically using the **certbot.** I can open the website from any browser without problems except when the website is linked and accessed from the facebook messenger app. There I get a popup telling me that there is a Security Error and there are problems with the security certificate for this website and nothing else.

Are these certificates not trusted by facebook or maybe I am missing something from configuring my certificate?

Comment: I have not heard of those not working in the FB in-app browser. Google some SSL checkers, input your site URL, see if those report any problems.

Comment: _“except when the website is linked and accessed from the facebook messenger app”_ - sure it’s absolutely the _correct_ URL, no www/non-www mismatch maybe, in combination with a certificate that covers only one of those?